# How can I copy Program Files/Bluestacks folder to another drive?

Tags: storage, bluestacks, android-pc

The `Bluestacks` folder is now 5GB large and is taking up too much space in my `C:\` drive, so I decided to move it to my `D:\` drive. But, when I do that, Bluestacks says the software is corrupt and I need to redownload Bluestacks from their website.

What can I do to change the location of Bluestacks?

Answer (score 5):

You should use a directory junction, which will make the old folder point to the new one (and automatically work when the old one is accessed as normal).

1. Fully exit Bluestacks
2. Move `C:\Program Files\Bluestacks` to `D:\Bluestacks\Files` (for example)
3. Likewise, move `C:\ProgramData\Bluestacks` to `D:\Bluestacks\Data`
4. Open a Command Prompt and run:

   ```
   mklink /D /J "C:\Program Files\Bluestacks" D:\Bluestacks\Files
   mklink /D /J "C:\ProgramData\Bluestacks" D:\Bluestacks\Data
   ```
5. Repeat similarly for any other directories you might need to move

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem and received the message "The syntax of the command is incorrect."
So, for directory path with gap, it is necessary to use quotation marks.

For example: (link is first, target is second)

`mklink /D /J "c:\Users\All Users\BlueStacks" "d:\_ProgramFiles\BlueStacks"`

Junction created for c:\Users\All Users\BlueStacks <<===>> d:_ProgramFiles\BlueStacks